# some char is getting converted into ( )

Tags: java

I have the following line of java code ..

```
 String description = new String(somestring.getBytes("ISO_8859_1"),"UTF-8");
```

Now it got stored in oracle column as

somestring1 -->  (), as an employer, attracts the most talented people to come work here.

somestring2 -->  Senior leaders in () have allocated a sufficient workforce.

So, here i m not able to understand what char is getting replaced by ().

Can anyone help here, which char is getting converted into () and getting stored in db.

Thanks,
-bond

Comment: Java will never convert any character to a pair of parens.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following line of java code

Well, you shouldn't. That line of code is fundamentally wrong and should not exist. It shows that you're doing something very wrong concerning encodings. Remove that line and fix whatever made you think you need that line, after reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken and will routinely corrupt text.

```
 String description = new String(somestring.getBytes("ISO_8859_1"),"UTF-8");
```

This instructs Java to take a sequence of UTF-16 unicode characters, and try to represent them as 8859-1 bytes. Each character not in 8859-1 will be converted to a '?'. Then, you are asking Java to pretend that those bytes are UTF-8, and turn then (back) into UTF-16. This will corrupt *another* swath of characters, since 8859-1 is not the same thing as UTF-8. By the time it gets to Oracle, it's a train wreck.